# How would you render this simple UI using React js?

Tags: api, user-interface, reactjs, single-page-application

I am new to React and I want to render the UI shown in the picture.

Description:
The UI consists of two main components the sidenav and the display container. The side nav shows the title and the number of questions/answers pairs in for that given tab. When the user clicks on a tab of the side nav, the display container outputs the selected tab as a title with the questions/answers pairs, see api.

EX: the user clicks tab2 on the side nav, the display container will show
Tab2

Question C
 Answer to Question C

Question D
 Answer to Question D

Question E
 Answer to Question E

And the side nav tab 2 will display 3, since there are 3 question/answer pairs.

[IMG]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEaCa.jpg[/IMG]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEaCa.jpg

The data will be fetched from an api in the json format
 [ { 'Tab1' : [
               {
                'question':'QuestionA', 
                'answer':'Answer to Question A'
               },
               {
                'question':'QuestionB', 
                'answer':'Answer to Question B'
               }
              ],
     'Tab2' : [
               {
                'question':'QuestionC', 
                'answer':'Answer to Question C'
               },
               {
                'question':'QuestionD', 
                'answer':'Answer to Question D'
               },
               {
                'question': 'QuestionE',
                'answer': 'Answer to Question E'
               }
              ]
         //... tab3, tab4, an so on...
      }

Answer (score 1):

Had you read reac-router tutorial ? if not here's the [link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/01-setting-up).

Please read it careful, after that, you will have a good understanding how to acomplish your requirement using react router Links in the easy way.

Or checkout this repo [Starter Kit](https://github.com/juavidn/starterkit) as starting point

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly the react router will be for the sidenav showing and displaying correct tab. And what do I use to read and display the api? What should I watch for specifically?

Comment: Lol if you read reactjs, you will know that it is just the V in the MVC, it's up to you to do "the rest of the job".

Comment: If you want you could use ... isomorphic fetch for fetching the api data ... redux to store the state .... and react router to switch between screens ! I'll be glad to provide you some gist as starting point !

Comment: OMG, that would be amazing! please

Comment: @Regex102 You can define express routes / react controllers to deal with the fetching. Alternatively, Davids suggestion will also work.

Comment: @Dandy which method will be easier? Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: @Regex102 That's pretty subjective to knowledge and experience. However, David is writing a Gist for you it seems, so I think that's the best route!

Comment: @Regex102 Hi man 5 days later but here is the repo https://github.com/juavidn/starterkit lol, I was "a little" busy the weekend, I used redux, redux-saga and fetch for api fetching... I hope it help you man ! Nice day !